# Get info from SQL Server each time or remember it in the program?

Tags: c#, sql-server

One of my app features get information from a database (1 string), and that string only changes every 24 hours.

The app doing check and read the database for that string every 1 minute or so for every user name, there are about 100 user names.

The question is what is better to do to read the information from SQL Server every 1 minute about the user or to store in in a value inside the app? And check for it again in 24 hours etc?

thanks.

Comment: Is your app always up and running?

Comment: who is changing the value ? it is possible to put caching layer so any change will go via it

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to do is to use the Caching built into .Net in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namepace. You can easily put the values from the database into the Cache object, and give it an expiry of 24 hours or the exact timeframes it should expire.

Answer (score 1):

Checking every minute seems a bit excessive for this.

If you are sure that the string doesn't change for 24hrs then you could store also a datetime for the last check and start a the requery only if there is a day difference between today and the last read.